# Работает ли указание языка программирования?

Tags: обсуждение, форматирование

Вроде явно прописываю

```
<!-- language: lang-vb -->
```

[Тут](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109) говорится, что таким образом должна переопределяться подсветка языка. Но всё равно [получается](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/452632/178988) какая-то фигня... Пробовал `lang-none` - эффект тот же.

Я что-то не учёл, или это переопределение не работает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас там определитель языка стоял не перед кодом:

> `<!-- language: lang-vb -->`
>
> Вот код на VB.NET (писал давно):
>
> ```
> Imports System.Management
> ```

[Переставил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/452632/revisions), теперь вроде бы подсвечивается верно.